# Не продолжается выполнение программы

Tags: python, python-3.x, pygame

Мне надо чтобы после достижения змейкой границ поля сразу же начинался цикл "finish". Однако этого не происходит, т.е. цикл "finish" не начинается сам, а только после того, как я произведу какое-либо действие (нажму любую клавишу и т.п.).

Вот сам код:

```
# What we are doing if we have collision
if snake_x >= 1051 or snake_x <= 209 or snake_y >= 841 or snake_y <= -1:
    # starting "game over" loop
    finish = True

while finish:
    window.fill((0, 0, 0)) ...
```

Что я делаю не правильно или может чего я НЕ делаю?

Comment: Добавьте [минимальный, самодостаточный и воспроизводимый пример](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) (кнопка [edit])

Answer (score 2):

Оберните код змейки в `while` и выходите из него по условию:

```
finish = True

while finish:
    # snake code

    if snake_x < 1051 or snake_x > 209 or snake_y < 841 or snake_y > -1:
        finish = False
```

или так:

```
while snake_x >= 1051 or snake_x <= 209 or snake_y >= 841 or snake_y <= -1:
    # snake code
```

Comment: Там похоже надо всё-таки знать что в остальном коде, мне кажется там всё не так просто.